# using HorizontalStackLayout and VerticalStackLayout with grid on maui XAML

Tags: maui

trying to build my first MAUI MAXL (UI) app
i have 3 elements that are organized using HorizontalStackLayout  and VerticalStackLayout
i want to use them as one struct and put them in a different location using grid
but only the Grid.Column is affecting the location
i put


and using
Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" for 1 block
and
Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" for the for second  block

why only the Column  is  affected ?

[image]

```
       <Grid   RowDefinitions="100,200,300">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="100,200,300">
                <VerticalStackLayout
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                    Spacing="5"
                    Padding="10,10"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label
                    x:Name="Kitchen"
                    Text="Kitchen"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="20"   
                    Padding="30,0"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                    <HorizontalStackLayout
                        Spacing="5"
                        Padding="0,0"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">

                        <Button
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        WidthRequest="60"
                        Text="OFF"
                        BackgroundColor="Gray"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"/>

                        <Button
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        WidthRequest="60"
                        Text="ON"
                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
                
                <VerticalStackLayout
                    Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
                    Spacing="5"
                    Padding="10,10"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label
                    x:Name="WorkRoom"
                    Text="WorkRoom"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="20"   
                    Padding="30,0"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                    <HorizontalStackLayout
                        Spacing="5"
                        Padding="0,0"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">

                        <Button
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        WidthRequest="60"
                        Text="OFF"
                        BackgroundColor="Gray"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"/>

                        <Button
                        BindingContext="WorkRoom"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        WidthRequest="60"
                        Text="ON"
                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </VerticalStackLayout>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating two Grids, one nested inside the other

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="100,200,300">
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="100,200,300">
```

you (I think) want a single grid

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="100,200,300" ColumnDefinitions="100,200,300" >
```

Comment: Please click on the 'checkmark` at the left of the question. This lets everyone know that this answer solved your problem.

Comment: where is the checkmark?